# Hiding extensions using .htaccess with network solutions

Tags: html, .htaccess

I'm wanting to remove the .html extension from a network solutions server using my .htaccess file. for example turning *example.com/foo.html* into *example.com/foo*

I have tried other stackoverflow solutions but none seem to work for me.

My current code is working on other Hostgator servers perfectly. any help would be appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
AddHandler server-parsed .html
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
AddHandler server-parsed .htm
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with the global Apache (webserver) configuration. The host needs to enable .htaccess support with the `AllowOverride` directive in your sites vhost entry. Additionally `ModRewrite` needs to be enabled. Both of these configuration options are considered "safe" and should be able to be enabled by your host.

[Hostgator.com](http://www.hostgator.com/) has really flexible Apache configurations with great defaults for a shared webhost imho.